# Newey-West Standard Errors for a GARCH(p, q) Model

Tags: autocorrelation, garch, robust-standard-error, neweywest

I am working with GARCH models (and analogues) recently and have a serious autocorrelation problem to deal with.

I made a research about robust estimation of standard errors for conditional variance models. However, all I can see is the applications of HC algorithms. I couldn't find a source about the HAC (neither an article nor an application). Can someone explain the reason behind this (why no HAC in GARCH, any restrictions?)

Is it possible to estimate autocorrelation corrected standard errors for GARCH type models? And how?

Answer (score 0):

There is less need for HAC standard errors in GARCH models than in some other models, as it is common to include an ARMA conditional mean model, and that takes care of the autocorrelation. So instead of a constant conditional mean + GARCH conditional variance, we use ARMA+GARCH. See Diebold ["The HAC Emperor has no Clothes"](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2015/10/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes.html) and ["The HAC Emperor has no Clothes: Part 2"](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes-part-2.html) for why you should prefer explicit ARMA modelling over HAC standard errors.

Packages like `rugarch` in R automatically report robust standard errors of GARCH models – though indeed robust against heteroskedasticity but not autocorrelation. There should be some notes about that in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf) or the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) (see p. 27).

Comment: Let alone the fact that ARMA can result with autocorrelated residuals (see Bollerslev 1986 about this); i dont work with ARMA. And those robust applications you wrote about are HC not HAC. Thank you for the answer but it wasn't what i asked. I edited the question a bit, pehaps it would be more clear like this.

Comment: @ErdemŞen, Too bad you do not work with ARMA, as it is often the more sensible choice compared to HAC. See Diebold ["The HAC Emperor has no Clothes: Part 2"](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes-part-2.html) (Part 1 is linked in that post.) (Of course, ARMA *can* result in autocorrelated residuals. Then you should either ignore that – see Diebold's post – or adjust the lag order to eliminate that.)